# React/Firebase. How can I dynamically change an ID when I'm clicking on the button?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uuid

How can I dynamically change an ID when I'm clicking on the button? When I click on the button, the product is added only once, the second time it is added only if the page is reloaded. How to fix it? I set `v4() (uuid)`. ID of the product is generating only after when I'm reloading the page

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
 const [list, setList] = useLocalStorage('data', {id: '', name: '', image: '', priceTotal: '', category: ''})



  const getProducts = async() => {
    const data = await ProductDataService.getAllProducts()
    setProducts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: v4()})))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts()
  }, [])


  const handleClick = async(item) => {
    if (list.indexOf(item) !== -1) return
    await addDoc(collection(db, 'list'), {
      id: item.id,
      image: item.image,
      name: item.name,
      priceTotal: item.priceTotal,
      category: item.category
    })
    setList([...list, item])
    console.log(item)
  }
```

Delete function:

```
    const deleteProduct = (id) => {
        setList((list) => list.filter((product) => id !== product.id))
    }
```

Database:

```
[
  {
    "products": {
      "id": 1,
      "category": "Consoles",
      "categoryId": 1,
      "image": "img",
      "name": "XBOX 360",
      "oldPrice": 1900,
      "priceTotal": 420
    }
  },
  {
    "products": {
      "id": 2,
      "category": "Steam",
      "categoryId": 4,
      "image": "img",
      "name": "500 STARS",
      "oldPrice": 1674,
      "priceTotal": 460
    }
  },
  {
    "products": {
      "id": 3,
      "category": "Smartphones",
      "categoryId": 3,
      "image": "img",
      "name": "Apple iPhone 13 Pro Max 256Gb ",
      "oldPrice": 2000,
      "priceTotal": 500
    }
  },
  {
    "products": {
      "id": 4,
      "category": "Headphones",
      "categoryId": 2,
      "image": "img",
      "name": "Apple AirPods Pro",
      "oldPrice": 1833,
      "priceTotal": 450
    }
  },
  {
    "products": {
      "id": 5,
      "category": "Consoles",
      "categoryId": 1,
      "image": "img",
      "name": "Sony PlayStation 5 Digital Edition",
      "oldPrice": 3250,
      "priceTotal": 678
    }
  },
  {
    "products": {
      "id": 6,
      "category": "Smartphones",
      "categoryId": 3,
      "image": "img",
      "name": "LENOVO P42 ",
      "oldPrice": 1500,
      "priceTotal": 300
    }
  },
  {
    "products": {
      "id": 7,
      "category": "Steam",
      "categoryId": 4,
      "image": "img",
      "name": "100 STARS",
      "oldPrice": 1000,
      "priceTotal": 3000
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a copy of the item and set new `id` in click handler and remove the first condition:

```js
  const handleClick = async(item) => {
    const newItem = { ...item, id: v4() }
    await addDoc(collection(db, 'list'), {
      id: newItem.id,
      image: newItem.image,
      name: newItem.name,
      priceTotal: newItem.priceTotal,
      category: newItem.category
    })
    setList([...list, newItem])
    console.log(newItem)
  }
```

Comment: @LLetovanec Unfortunately, this is not what I need. I still can't add the same product to the cart multiple times.

Comment: See updated answer, i removed the condition that was causing the item not being added, did you have a reason to put it there?

Comment: @LLetovanec Yes, I did. When you removed it, the goods began to be added to the cart, but when I'm going to the cart and trying to delete them, all the same goods are deleted from the cart. I added a delete function here. Maybe this will help you?

Comment: Can you check if the `item.id` is same before calling this line `item.id = v4()` and after calling it?

Comment: @LLetovanec No, they're different. When i click on the button, the product `id` keeps changing

Comment: Hmm, then I don't get why multiple products with different IDs should be removed by the `deleteProduct` function you added

Comment: @LLetovanec Oh! I'm sorry! I have an error `Encountered two children with the same key`, when I'm deleting the same products.

Comment: For that I would need to see JSX - how you render those items. Can you update your post and add it there please?

Comment: @LLetovanec I have added a database, but I am using Firestore Database. I hope this data that I sent will be enough. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've actually meant part where you are rendering items in react, you are probably not using `key` property correctly there that's why you got that error, check this https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @LLetovanec Got it! For convenience, I have created a [codesandbox template](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-firefly-e0gre9) with all information. Please check it out

Comment: Thanks that helped! I've updated the answer, you need to create copy of the item. Without creating a copy the ID was updated also on the previous item after clicking multiple times on the same item